# Oracle 01830 error while converting string to date in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, type-conversion, ora-01830

Following is the first few lines of my stored procedure in oracle. All I am trying to do is to pass a string into procedure, convert it into date and use it in a query. But it doesn't seem to work. Currently, the error I am being thrown at is as following:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
>
> ORA-06512: at "APPS.PORDUCTPLANNINGFORECAST", line 26
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPS.PorductPlanningForecast (
   vDateFrom        IN varchar2,
   vDateTo          IN varchar2 , 
   vForecastSetDPL2 IN varchar2, 
   out              SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS 
  L_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR; 
  vfrom    date; 
  vto      date;
BEGIN
  vfrom:= TO_DATE(vDateFrom,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
  vto:=TO_DATE(vDateTo,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

the lines having `TO_DATE()` are line 26 and 27. Also, the format I am passing in is through c# which is `System.DateTime` format(`"01/08/2013 12:00:00 AM"`) converted into a string and then passed through `add` parameter as  gave up on passing date as date due to date conversion errors. Please help..

Comment: tried changing nls parameter setting setting it to the format provided in to_date but it didnt work.

Comment: Try: to_date( string, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM" )

Comment: how do i keep it variable?AM/PM? also now i am getting the following error:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing in a string of the following format `01/08/2013 12:00:00 AM` then in order to successfully convert that string into a date datatype you should use the following format mask `'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'` which includes meridian indicator:

```
to_date(vDateFrom, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')
```

---

> but how do i make it variable?it could be PM too

Meridian indicators are interchangeable. For both strings `01/08/2013 2:00:00 AM` and `01/08/2013 2:00:00 PM` for instance, you can use date format model with one of the meridian indicators, whether it `AM` or `PM`. Here is an example:

```
select to_date('01/08/2013 2:00:00 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') as res
  from dual
```

Result:

```
Res 
-----------
01.08.2013 2:00:00 


select to_date('01/08/2013 2:00:00 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') as res
  from dual

Res 
-----------------
01.08.2013 14:00:00
```

Comment: And now it yields the following error:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: thank you, could you also help me with a subsequent error?

ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: @user1451836 Would be nice if you provided more detailed information about under what circumstances that exception is raised.

Comment: Right after making the changes as :

    `BEGIN
    vfrom:= TO_DATE(vDateFrom,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM');
    vto:=TO_DATE(vDateTo,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM');`

I got the error of ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: I am passing them in String variable.it originates from a MySQL date type converted and stored as string in a string variable and then sent in here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36530/discussion-between-nicholas-krasnov-and-user1451836)